# Select rows with min value by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a problems that bugs me for some time… hopefully anybody here can help me.

I got the following data frame

```
f <- c('a','a','b','b','b','c','d','d','d','d')
v1 <- c(1.3,10,2,10,10,1.1,10,3.1,10,10)
v2 <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(f,v1,v2)
```

f is a factor; v1 and v2 are values.
For each level of f, I want only want to keep one row: the one that has the lowest value of v1 in this factor level.

```
f   v1  v2
a   1.3 1
b   2   3
c   1.1 6
d   3.1 8
```

I tried various things with aggregate, ddply, by, tapply… but nothing seems to work. For any suggestions, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using DWin's solution, `tapply` can be avoided using `ave`.

```
df[ df$v1 == ave(df$v1, df$f, FUN=min), ]
```

This gives another speed-up, as shown below. Mind you, this is also dependent on the number of levels. I give this as I notice that `ave` is far too often forgotten about, although it is one of the more powerful functions in R.

```
f <- rep(letters[1:20],10000)
v1 <- rnorm(20*10000)
v2 <- 1:(20*10000)
df <- data.frame(f,v1,v2)

> system.time(df[ df$v1 == ave(df$v1, df$f, FUN=min), ])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05 

> system.time(df[ df$v1 %in% tapply(df$v1, df$f, min), ])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.03    0.29 

> system.time(lapply(split(df, df$f), FUN = function(x) {
+             vec <- which(x[3] == min(x[3]))
+             return(x[vec, ])
+         })
+  .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.56    0.00    0.58 

> system.time(df[tapply(1:nrow(df),df$f,function(i) i[which.min(df$v1[i])]),]
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.19 

> system.time( ddply(df, .var = "f", .fun = function(x) {
+     return(subset(x, v1 %in% min(v1)))
+     }
+ )
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.28    0.00    0.28
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer! Great that you added the timings too.

Comment: Thanks for that answer and the timings. How would I adapt that to more than one factor? Let's say I have f1 and f2 as factors, and I want the min-value for each combination... I tried both c() and list(), but it didn't work.

Comment: @donodarazao : see `?ave` : ave(x,factor1,factor2,factor3,factor4,...,FUN=min)

Comment: @hadley: thx, I didn't even realize I corrected a tricky bug.

Answer (score 16):

A `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,.SD[which.min(v1)], by = f]

##   f  v1 v2
## 1: a 1.3  1
## 2: b 2.0  3
## 3: c 1.1  6
## 4: d 3.1  8
```

Or, more efficiently

```
DT[DT[,.I[which.min(v1)],by=f][['V1']]]
```

## some benchmarking

```
f <- rep(letters[1:20],100000)
v1 <- rnorm(20*100000)
v2 <- 1:(20*100000)
df <- data.frame(f,v1,v2)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
f1<-function(){df2<-df[order(df$f,df$v1),]
               df2[!duplicated(df2$f),]}

f2<-function(){df2<-df[order(df$v1),]
               df2[!duplicated(df2$f),]}

f3<-function(){df[ df$v1 == ave(df$v1, df$f, FUN=min), ]}


f4 <- function(){DT[,.SD[which.min(v1)], by = f]}

f5 <- function(){DT[DT[,.I[which.min(v1)],by=f][['V1']]]}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(),f2(),f3(),f4(), f5(),times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# f1() 3254.6620 3265.4760 3286.5440 3411.4054 3475.4198     5
# f2() 1630.8572 1639.3472 1651.5422 1721.4670 1738.6684     5
# f3()  172.2639  174.0448  177.4985  179.9604  184.7365     5
# f4()  206.1837  209.8161  209.8584  210.4896  210.7893     5
# f5()  105.5960  106.5006  107.9486  109.7216  111.1286     5
```

The `.I` approach is the winner ([FR #2330](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=2330) will hopefully render the elegance of the `.SD` approach similarly fast when implemented).

Answer (score 8):

With `plyr`, I'd use:

```
ddply(df, .var = "f", .fun = function(x) {
    return(subset(x, v1 %in% min(v1)))
    }
)
```

Give that a try and see if it returns what you want.

Comment: Or more simply: `ddply(df, "f", subset, v1 == min(v1))`

Comment: Well, solution is pretty, but with many levels and few values per level only is extremely slow...

Answer (score 6):

Another `tapply` solution, with no unnecessary scanning of vector with `%in%`:

```
df[tapply(1:nrow(df),df$f,function(i) i[which.min(df$v1[i])]),]
```

EDIT: This will left only first row in case of a tie.

EDIT2: Impressed by `ave`, I've made additional improvements:

```
df[sapply(split(1:nrow(df),df$f),function(x) x[which.min(df$v1[x])]),]
```

On my machine (using Joris' benchmark data):

```
> system.time(df[ df$v1 == ave(df$v1, df$f, FUN=min), ])
   user  system elapsed
  0.022   0.000   0.021
> system.time(df[sapply(split(1:nrow(df),df$f),function(x) x[which.min(df$v1[x])]),])
   user  system elapsed
  0.006   0.000   0.007
```

Comment: Well, mbq, I voted yours up. And like Matt with mine, I had to work yours through to "see" its inner workings.

Comment: @DWin Sorry for this %in% remark, I maybe tend to overestimate efficiency :| And I agree that all solutions are pretty complicated; `by` solution is IMO quite readable but the result is awful (-;

Answer (score 6):

This is the dplyr-way to filter for the minimum `v1` values by groups of `f`:

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  group_by(f) |>
  slice_min(v1)
```

See the `?slice_min` help page for options such as whether or not to include ties (default includes them), or options to keep more than 1 lowest value (e.g., bottom 5 or bottom 10%).

You can also do it more explicitly:

```
df %>%
  group_by(f) %>%
  filter(v1 == min(v1))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: f
#
#  f  v1 v2
#1 a 1.3  1
#2 b 2.0  3
#3 c 1.1  6
#4 d 3.1  8
```

In cases of ties in `v1`, this would result in multiple rows per group of `f`. If you want to avoid that, you can use:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(f) %>% 
  filter(rank(v1, ties.method= "first") == 1)
```

This way, you'll only get the first row in case of ties. You could alternatively use `ties.method = "random"` or others as described in the help file.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tapply solution;

```
> df[ df$v1 %in% tapply(df$v1, df$f, min), ]

  f  v1 v2
1 a 1.3  1
3 b 2.0  3
6 c 1.1  6
8 d 3.1  8
```

In your example it only picks out one per group, but if there were ties this method would show them all. (As would Parker's and Luštrik's I suspect.)

Comment: Excellent point regarding ties.  Nice function, too - took me a few reads and a glance at ?tapply to figure out what was going on.

Comment: Wow, amazing! The ddply-solution from Matt works, but took around 2 min in my real data frame (~10,000 rows). This solution gives the same result, but takes less than a 1 second. Pretty elegant, thanks!

Comment: Something is going wrong if ddply takes 2 minutes on 10,000 observations. Plus this method is not always going to return the correct results - think about the case where 2 is the lowest value for one group and the second lowest for another group.  It's just luck that it works for this example.

Comment: Maybe it's because there are 7,700 factor levels in the 10,000 observations? I tried it again with your ddply-solution and it really takes that long...

Comment: As per hadley's point, this solution is incorrect. Test on input `df = data.frame(f = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), v1 = c(2, 3, 1, 2))` - correct result is a 2-row data frame, this code produces 3 rows. The answer really should be corrected or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, my thinking power is depleted, and this ugly solution is all I can come up with at almost 1 am.

```
lapply(split(df, df$f), FUN = function(x) {
            vec <- which(x[3] == min(x[3]))
            return(x[vec, ])
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `order` and `!duplicated`, but you would only get the first on ties.

```
df2 <- df[order(df$f,df$v1),]
df2[!duplicated(df2$f),]

  f  v1 v2
1 a 1.3  1
3 b 2.0  3
6 c 1.1  6
8 d 3.1  8
```

**Timings**

```
f1<-function(){df2<-df[order(df$f,df$v1),]
df2[!duplicated(df2$f),]}

f2<-function(){df2<-df[order(df$v1),]
df2[!duplicated(df2$f),]}

f3<-function(){df[ df$v1 == ave(df$v1, df$f, FUN=min), ]}

library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(f1(),f2(),f3())
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 f1()          100   38.16 7.040590     36.66     1.48         NA        NA
2 f2()          100   20.54 3.789668     19.30     1.23         NA        NA
3 f3()          100    5.42 1.000000      4.96     0.46         NA        NA
```

Comment: Order over `v1` is sufficient. Nice solution, how about timing?

Comment: @Marek Thanks, didn't think about not really needing to order on `f`. This seems to speed it up by about 2x, but its still a fair bit slower than Joris Meys' `ave` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `by`

```
do.call(rbind, unname(by(df, df$f, function(x) x[x$v1 == min(x$v1),])))
##   f  v1 v2
## 1 a 1.3  1
## 3 b 2.0  3
## 6 c 1.1  6
## 8 d 3.1  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse

```
df %>%
  arrange(v1) %>% # You can also do arrange(f, v1)
  distinct(f, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I also like the previous answer from @talat

```
df %>%
  group_by(f) %>%
  filter(v1 == min(v1))
```

but the first one avoid grouping and ungrouping.

Comment: It is my personal opinion that it looks very similar to the answer of @talat.