# how to efficiently select rows with minimum value in R?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Only keep min value for each factor level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189807/only-keep-min-value-for-each-factor-level)

Here is my problem, I want to select rows with minimum value in specified column.
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b","b"),value=1:4)
```

The result I want is

```
 A value
 a     1
 b     3
```

I could do with `by` and `ddply`, but they are quite slow when df is huge and has many different value in `A`.

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,df$A, function(x) x[which.min(abs(x$value)),],simplify=FALSE))

ddply(df, ~A, function(x){x[which.min(abs(x$value)),]})
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I selected that possible duplicate because it has some benchmarks in it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Btw, in case some search tricks help,  I found that question by searching for "[r] +which.min +benchmark" which returned that single question. The trick I suppose is going from the word "efficient" to searching for "benchmark".

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` is quite fast for large data.frames if you set the key.

```
dt <- data.table(df, key="A")
dt[, list(value=min(value)), by=A]
```

References:

- [Quick intro](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)
- [Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)

Comment: Interesting. How to return other columns instead of "value" and "A"?

Comment: You can have multiple "by" columns by passing the column names as a vector (e.g. `by=c("A", "Bcolumn", "Ccolumn")`). You can compute multiple statistics by including them in the list call (e.g. `list(min_value=min(value), max_value=max(value))`.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt make myself clear. Suppose there are three column, "B", in df, with the command I only got "value" and "A", how to make to output column "B" as well.

Comment: That depends on what you want to calculate. If you want the minimum by A and B then you'll want to use my `by` syntax above. If you want to calculate something on B then you'll use the `list` syntax but replace value with B. If you want something else then example data would help as the syntax will differ depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

tapply does this:

```
> tapply(df$value, df$A, min)
a b 
1 3
```

**Edited:**  Using `by` instead of `tapply`, we can retain the row names:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b","b"),value=11:14)
df
##   A value
## 1 a    11
## 2 a    12
## 3 b    13
## 4 b    14

do.call(rbind, unname(by(df, df$A, function(x) x[x$value == min(x$value),])))
##   A value
## 1 a    11
## 3 b    13
```

Comment: It is fast, but I lost other information. How to return the row index?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  I thought you wanted the values (which here agree with the indices).